# Compare each matrix row to a vector

Tags: r

I have a 3-column matrix, and I want to compare its rows with a vector. And I know that the easiest way is through `apply(table==vector,1,sum)>(length(vector)-1)`, but since I kept getting wrong rows marked I started to dig into partial results. Below there is my code and a mistake R seems to be doing.

```
transition_matrix<-cbind(permutations(n=7,r=4,v=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6),repeats.allowed=T),prob=0,n=1)
vector<-c(1,0,1)
table <- transition_matrix[,c(1:3)]
table[59,]
>0 1 1
(table==vector)[59,]
>TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

So I am just puzzled staring at my code and honestly not understanding why it does not work. I might be missing something because if I compare directly row number 59 with the vector I get the right result.

Comment: What if you do (table[59,] == vector)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Chi Pak notes, `table == vector` is operating down columns, but you want to compare each row to the vector.

One way to get the behavior you want is to transpose the matrix before comparing to the vector, and then re-transposing afterwards.

Sample data:

```
(table <- matrix(rep(0:2, 4), 4))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    1    2
# [2,]    1    2    0
# [3,]    2    0    1
# [4,]    0    1    2

(vector <- c(0, 0, 1))
# [1] 0 0 1
```

Calculation:

```
t(t(table) == vector)
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# [4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

One advantage of this compared to an approach using `apply` is that all the operations are vectorized, which means this will be a good deal more efficient on large matrices. To see this, let's look at a matrix with one million rows:

```
set.seed(144)
table <- matrix(sample(0:1, 3e6, replace=TRUE), 1e6)
system.time(t(t(table) == vector))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.066   0.013   0.078 
system.time(t(apply(table,1,function(x) x==vector)))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   2.508   0.057   2.576
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Explanation

When you compare a `vector` to a `matrix` it does so column-wise

See the following reproducible example

```
table <- matrix(c(rep(0,60),rep(1,60),rep(1,60)),ncol=3)
vector <- c(1,0,1)

head(table==vector)

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[5,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[6,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

`1,1` is FALSE because `vector[1]==1` and `table[1,1]==0`. `2,1` is TRUE because `vector[2]==0` and `table[2,1]==0`, etc.

#### Solution

```
head(t(apply(table,1,function(x) x==vector)))

      [,1]  [,2] [,3]
[1,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
[4,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
[5,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
[6,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
```