# Comparing jth Matrix column with jth Vector entry

Tags: r

I have the following matrix

```
M = 3
K = 10
H = matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1),M,K,byrow=FALSE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    0    1    1    0    1    1     0
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[3,]    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    1    1     1
```

I'm trying to find a generic way, for calculating

```
H[,1]==1 & H[,2]==0 & H[,3]==1 & H[,4]==0 & H[,5]==1 & H[,6]==0 & H[,7]==1 & H[,8]==1 & H[,9]==0 & H[,10]==1
```

where the order of 0 and 1 can be arbitrary, i.e. I would like equivalently to be able to calculate

```
H[,1]==0 & H[,2]==0 & H[,3]==0 & H[,4]==0 & H[,5]==1 & H[,6]==0 & H[,7]==1 & H[,8]==0 & H[,9]==0 & H[,10]==0
```

in general all the possible 0-1 combination.

I stick with the first example. I first try to check if it possible to compare a `j` column of the matrix `H`  with a `j` entry of the vector `c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1)`, i.e. a particular combination of 0-1.

```
H[1:dim(H)[1],1:K]==c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1)
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6] [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

It seems that it compares the first column of matrix `H` with the first three elements of the vector and continues that way, i.e `H[,1]` with the `c(1,0,1)` then `H[,2]` with the `c(0,1,0)` etc., totally missing my goal.

Is there a proper that overcomes that comparison problem?

Comment: Related: [Compare matrix with elements in vector by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469053/compare-matrix-with-elements-in-vector-by-row); [Compare each matrix row to a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45527620/compare-rows-to-a-vector).

Comment: @Henrik Thank you very much for the recommendations, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with `paste0` + `data.frame`

```
> do.call(paste0, data.frame(H)) == paste0(v, collapse = "")
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `colSums` to create a logical vector

```
colSums(t(H) == v1) == ncol(H)
```

where

```
v1 <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1)
```

Comment: I think you are right.  I was just checking the output comparing to other solution

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
x1 <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1)
x2 <- H[2, ]

apply(H, 1, function(y) all(y == x1))
#> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
apply(H, 1, function(y) all(y == x2))
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```